# jquery hide specific elements with the same class

Tags: jquery, class, select

Got a table with tds with different classes.
I need something that selects all elements which contain a specific class until the class changes.

Example:

```
<table class="TableClass">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td class="I">&nbsp;TOP</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.1</td>
            <td class="II">&nbsp;First</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.1.1</td>
            <td class="III">&nbsp;asdf</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.1.2</td>
            <td class="III">&nbsp;asdf</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.2</td>
            <td class="II">&nbsp;Second</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.2.1</td>
            <td class="III">&nbsp;Anmeldename</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click on "First" all elements with class "III" have to hide but the elements with class "III" after "Second" not.

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: My problem is, I event dont know have a kind of idea. I can do basic things with jquery but thats too much for my little knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I tried. This may not be the optimized, but working for me.

```html
<script>
var flg = 0;    
$("tr").find("td").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('class') != '' && $(this).attr('class') != undefined) {            
        if ($(this).hasClass('III')) {
            if (flg != 2) {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                flg = 1;
            }
        } else {
            if (flg == 1) {
                flg = 2;
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```